# Function search of a motive gives an error with capital letters

Tags: c

I have implemented this function in C to find a motive in a given file. 
So the file contains the messages as below: 
For example `ISI`, `JE SERAI INGENIEURE` etc are messages.

```
19971230 20220512 JE SERAI INGENIEURE
19950511 20211230 ISI
19971230 20301123 INFORMATIQUE C'EST LA VIE
20020809 20081025 LANGAGE DE PROGRAMMATION
20070905 20201104 ECOLE INGENIEUR
19990102 20051025 ORDINATEUR
20081212 20200312 JE SUIS
```

Each information is put in a linked list.

This is my code :

```
void trouverMotif(message_t ** tete, char motif[])
{
    message_t *temp = *tete;
    char *ptr = motif;
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",temp->text);
        i = 0;
        j = 0;

        while(temp->text[i] != ptr[j] && temp->text[i] != '\0')
        {
            i++;
        }

        if(temp->text[i] == ptr[j])
        {
            while(temp->text[i] != '\0' && ptr[j] != '\0' && ptr[j] == temp->text[i])
            {
                j++;
                i++;
            }

            if(ptr[j] == '\0')
            {
                printf("%s", temp->text);
            }
        }
        temp = temp->suivant;
    }
}
```

So the result that I want to have is that, if I put the motif = "INGE" , the result gives me the messages that contain "INGE", in my case; JE SERAI INGENIEURE and ECOLE INGENIEUR.

The problem is that the result that I obtain is only ECOLE INGENIEUR and not both of them. When I change the messages to lower case letters, it gives the right result (both of them). How is this possible?

Comment: Are you allowed to use useful functions such as `strstr()`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler no :/

Comment: Did you consider writing your own `mq_strstr()` to mimic the standard function?  Would that simplify your code?

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
   while(temp->text[i] != ptr[j] && temp->text[i] != '\0')
    {
        i++;
    }

    if(temp->text[i] == ptr[j])
    {
        while(temp->text[i] != '\0' && ptr[j] != '\0' && ptr[j] == temp->text[i])
        {
            j++;
            i++;
        }

        if(ptr[j] == '\0')
        {
            printf("%s", temp->text);
        }
    }
```

fails if the first time the first character of *ptr* is present in *temp->text* is not the sequence you search

for instance if *ptr* is "AZE" and `temp->text` is "...A AZE" your first while set *i* to 3, and after you compare "AZE" and "A AZE" and there are not equals

---

Here a proposal, the code has to check if *motif* is a substring of each message's text, so the more natural is to define *contient* equivalent of *strstr* :

```
char * contient(const char * meule, const char * aiguille)
{
  /* strstr */
  while (*meule) {
    const char * p1 = meule;
    const char * p2 = aiguille;

    if (*p1 == *p2) {
      do {
        p1 += 1;
        p2 += 1;

        if (*p2 == 0)
          return (char *) meule;
      } while  (*p1 == *p2);
    }

    meule += 1;
  }

  return NULL;
}

void trouverMotif(message_t ** tete, char motif[])
{
  message_t *temp = *tete;

  while(temp != NULL)
  {
    /* printf("%s\n", p); */

    if (contient(temp->text, motif) != NULL)
      printf("'%s' found in '%s'\n", motif, temp->text);

    temp = temp->suivant;
  }
}
```

---

For instance if I add :

```
typedef struct message_t {
  char * text;
  struct message_t * suivant;
}  message_t;

message_t * mk(char * t, message_t * n)
{
  message_t * r = malloc(sizeof(message_t));

  r->text = t;
  r->suivant = n;
  return r;
}

int main()
{
  message_t * tete = mk("19971230 20220512 JE SERAI INGENIEURE",
                        mk("19950511 20211230 ISI",
                           mk("19971230 20301123 INFORMATIQUE C'EST LA VIE",
                              mk("20020809 20081025 LANGAGE DE PROGRAMMATION",
                                 mk("20070905 20201104 ECOLE INGENIEUR",
                                    mk("19990102 20051025 ORDINATEUR",
                                       mk("20081212 20200312 JE SUIS ", NULL)))))));


  trouverMotif(&tete, "INGE");
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
'INGE' found in '19971230 20220512 JE SERAI INGENIEURE
'INGE' found in '20070905 20201104 ECOLE INGENIEUR
```

Remark : you do not need `trouverMotif(message_t ** tete, char motif[])` because you do not modify *tete*, so `trouverMotif(message_t * tete, char motif[])` is enough

Comment: so what do I do?

Comment: @MimozaQati are you allowed to use strcmp ?

Comment: @MimozaQati answer edited to add a proposal more additional code to be able to run and show that works

Answer (score 0):

When you search for `INGE` in `JE SERAI INGENIEUR` the `i` in `SERAI` will match `I` in `INGE`, and advance to `N. When you reach`INGENIEUR`, you will no longer match the`I`

Comment: so what do I do to avoid this? @jo-art